# BizTalk Mapping: How to show a parent record once only if there are 1 or more child records. Otherwise, do not show parent record

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I would like to show a parent record only if one or more child records have values. Otherwise, I do not want the parent record to show up in the output at all.
If this is the input

```
<PO_ALLOWANCES_CHARGES>
    <ALLOW_CHARGE>
        <TYPE/>
        <CODE/>
        <PERCENTQUALIFIER/>
        <PERCENT/>
        <RATE/>
        <METHODOFHANDLING/>
        <DESCRIPTION/>
        <AMOUNT/>
    </ALLOW_CHARGE>
</PO_ALLOWANCES_CHARGES>
```

Then I would like there to be no output

If this is the input

```
<PO_ALLOWANCES_CHARGES>
    <ALLOW_CHARGE>
        <TYPE>A</TYPE>
        <CODE>ABCD</CODE>
        <PERCENTQUALIFIER>A</PERCENTQUALIFIER>
        <PERCENT>14.598</PERCENT>
        <RATE>18.54</RATE>
        <METHODOFHANDLING>AB</METHODOFHANDLING>
        <DESCRIPTION>TEST Allow Charge Desc</DESCRIPTION>
        <AMOUNT>104.52</AMOUNT>
    </ALLOW_CHARGE>
        <ALLOW_CHARGE>
        <TYPE>B</TYPE>
        <CODE>BCDE</CODE>
        <PERCENTQUALIFIER>B</PERCENTQUALIFIER>
        <PERCENT>24.598</PERCENT>
        <RATE>28.54</RATE>
        <METHODOFHANDLING>BC</METHODOFHANDLING>
        <DESCRIPTION>TEST Allow Charge Desc 02</DESCRIPTION>
        <AMOUNT>204.52</AMOUNT>
    </ALLOW_CHARGE>
</PO_ALLOWANCES_CHARGES>
```

Then I would like this to be the output

```
<ns0:POAllowAndCharges>
    <ns3:POAckAllowAndChargeType>
        <ns3:ChargeId>1</ns3:ChargeId>
        <ns3:ChargeType>A</ns3:ChargeType>
        <ns3:ChargeCode>ABCD</ns3:ChargeCode>
        <ns3:PctQualifier>A</ns3:PctQualifier>
        <ns3:Pct>14.598</ns3:Pct>
        <ns3:Rate>18.54</ns3:Rate>
        <ns3:MethodOfHandling>AB</ns3:MethodOfHandling>
        <ns3:ChargeDesc>TEST Allow Charge Desc</ns3:ChargeDesc>
        <ns3:Amount>104.52</ns3:Amount>
    </ns3:POAckAllowAndChargeType>
    <ns3:POAckAllowAndChargeType>
        <ns3:ChargeId>2</ns3:ChargeId>
        <ns3:ChargeType>B</ns3:ChargeType>
        <ns3:ChargeCode>BCDE</ns3:ChargeCode>
        ns3:PctQualifier>B</ns3:PctQualifier>
        <ns3:Pct>24.598</ns3:Pct>
        <ns3:Rate>28.54</ns3:Rate>
        <ns3:MethodOfHandling>BC</ns3:MethodOfHandling>
        <ns3:ChargeDesc>TEST Allow Charge Desc 02</ns3:ChargeDesc>
        <ns3:Amount>204.52</ns3:Amount>
    </ns3:POAckAllowAndChargeType>
</ns0:POAllowAndCharges>
```

With this mapping, I get the proper output if there are child records and values. However, the output contains the parent record  <ns0:POAllowAndCharges>
[image: With this mapping, I get the proper output if there are child records and values. However, the output contains the parent record <ns0:POAllowAndCharges />]

With this mapping, there is no parent record if there are not child records or values but the output is not correct if there are values
[image: With this mapping, there is no parent record if there are not child records or values but the output is not correct if there are values]

This is the output if with the second mapping if there are child records and values

```
    <ns0:POAllowAndCharges>
        <ns3:POAckAllowAndChargeType>
            <ns3:ChargeId>1</ns3:ChargeId>
            <ns3:ChargeType>A</ns3:ChargeType>
            <ns3:ChargeCode>ABCD</ns3:ChargeCode>
            <ns3:PctQualifier>A</ns3:PctQualifier>
            <ns3:Pct>14.598</ns3:Pct>
            <ns3:Rate>18.54</ns3:Rate>
            <ns3:MethodOfHandling>AB</ns3:MethodOfHandling>
            <ns3:ChargeDesc>TEST Allow Charge Desc</ns3:ChargeDesc>
            <ns3:Amount>104.52</ns3:Amount>
        </ns3:POAckAllowAndChargeType>
    </ns0:POAllowAndCharges>
    <ns0:POAllowAndCharges>
        <ns3:POAckAllowAndChargeType>
            <ns3:ChargeId>2</ns3:ChargeId>
            <ns3:ChargeType>B</ns3:ChargeType>
            <ns3:ChargeCode>BCDE</ns3:ChargeCode>
            <ns3:PctQualifier>B</ns3:PctQualifier>
            <ns3:Pct>24.598</ns3:Pct>
            <ns3:Rate>28.54</ns3:Rate>
            <ns3:MethodOfHandling>BC</ns3:MethodOfHandling>
            <ns3:ChargeDesc>TEST Allow Charge Desc 02</ns3:ChargeDesc>
            <ns3:Amount>204.52</ns3:Amount>
        </ns3:POAckAllowAndChargeType>
    </ns0:POAllowAndCharges>
```

It causes the parent record to be duplicated with each iteration of the child records. I would like all of the child records to be contained within the one Parent record.

Does anyone know how I might achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were nearly there

1. You don't need the looping functoid, it already knows to loop.
2. You need to have the Cumulative Concatenate Functoid for the POAllowAndCharges

[image: ![BizTalk Map]

Comment: Awesome. This worked perfectly. Thank you for helping me out with this issue!